# Flash light app

Tags: android, flash, android-camera

i am making simple torch app by using switch button.On clicking  switch button  flash mode is on but it is not switching off.

**my code:**

```
package com.shibli.torch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Switch;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Switch  s;
android.hardware.Camera cam;
Parameters params;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    s=(Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean v) {


  if( s.isChecked()){
try {
    cam = android.hardware.Camera.open();
    params = cam.getParameters();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
}
finally{
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    cam.setParameters(params);
    cam.startPreview();
    ;
}} 
 else
 {
 params = cam.getParameters();
 params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
 cam.setParameters(params);
 cam.stopPreview();
 }



        }
    });

}


}
```

**xml layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#000000"  >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the finaly() is not a good idea in that case, because if the cam failed to initialize, You will get a NullPointerException. Second, use the boolean value from the checkedChangeListener. I would do it similar to this way (not tested, but should point You to the right directiopn):

```
      s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {


    if(isChecked==true){
          try {
           cam = android.hardware.Camera.open();
           params = cam.getParameters();
           params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
           cam.setParameters(params);
           cam.startPreview();

          } catch (RuntimeException e) {
               //Toast for the user, that it doesn´t work
          }    
        }else{

      if(cam!=null){
      params = cam.getParameters();
      params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
      cam.setParameters(params);
      cam.stopPreview();
    }
 }
```

Comment: permission and feature for camera set in manifest? can You update Your code please?